# JSON file not loading with Leaflet

Tags: json, leaflet, geojson

I'm trying to figure out why this JSON file will not load with Leaflet. The JSON file contains an object called "seabeds" which I use to create a map layer in the code below. The JSON file is [located here.](http://scs14004.geog2510.uconn.edu/seabeds.json) The html file is [located here](http://scs14004.geog2510.uconn.edu/seabeds.html) and code copied below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/0.7.3/leaflet.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="map" style="position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 100%;"></div>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/0.7.3/leaflet.js"></script>
    <script src="seabeds.json"></script>
    <script>

        var map = L.map('map').setView([41.55437, -72.61202], 9); 

        L.tileLayer('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibWFwYm94IiwiYSI6ImNpandmbXliNDBjZWd2M2x6bDk3c2ZtOTkifQ._QA7i5Mpkd_m30IGElHziw', {
            maxZoom: 18,
            id: 'mapbox.streets'
        }).addTo(map);

        function style(feature) {
            return {
                weight: 2,
                opacity: 1,
                color: 'white',
                dashArray: '3',
                fillOpacity: 0.7
            };
        }

        var seabeds_layer = L.geoJson(seabeds, {
            style: style 
        }).addTo(map);
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The features in your GeoJSON are in a projected coordinate system, not longitude and latitude. There are basically two ways to fix this. First, if you have exported this dataset from a GIS program, you can convert the projection to a geographic coordinate system with the WGS84 datum, then export to GeoJSON again. It should then display correctly.

Second, you can use [Proj4Leaflet](http://kartena.github.io/Proj4Leaflet/), which will allow you to display projected data in Leaflet. One complication in this case is that the GeoJSON does not have a named [coordinate reference system object](http://geojson.org/geojson-spec.html#coordinate-reference-system-objects), which is necessary for [L.Proj.GeoJson](http://kartena.github.io/Proj4Leaflet/api/#l-proj-geojson) to work. Looking at your feature properties, I guessed that this might be using a state/regional projection, so I did a quick search for [Connecticut on spatialreference.org](http://www.spatialreference.org/ref/?search=Connecticut) and picked `NAD 1983 StatePlane Connecticut FIPS 0600 Feet`, which is either a lucky guess or something very close to the actual coordinate system used, because it seems to work.

Because Proj4Leaflet only includes a few coordinate systems by default, you need to specify the projection parameters, which you can get from the [Proj4js format](http://www.spatialreference.org/ref/esri/102656/proj4js/) link on the spatialreference.org page for the projection:

```
proj4.defs("EPSG:102656", "+proj=lcc +lat_1=41.2 +lat_2=41.86666666666667 +lat_0=40.83333333333334 +lon_0=-72.75 +x_0=304800.6096 +y_0=152400.3048 +ellps=GRS80 +datum=NAD83 +to_meter=0.3048006096012192 +no_defs");
```

Then, create a CRS object with the projection name and add it to your seabeds GeoJSON object:

```
var crs = {
  "type": "name",
  "properties": {
    "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::102656"
  }
};

seabeds.crs = crs;
```

Then create your layer with `L.Proj.geoJson`:

```
var seabeds_layer = L.Proj.geoJson(seabeds, {
  style: style
}).addTo(map);
```

And then it'll work! Here's an example fiddle:

http://fiddle.jshell.net/nathansnider/cjjrpyhx/

Comment: Nathan, thank you! I appreciate your thoughtful and thorough response. I will try your suggestions right away.